# Linking Number $0$ When One Knot is a Boundary

Tags: differential-topology, knot-theory

I am given two smooth knots $K$ and $L$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  I am also given that $K$ is the boundary of an oriented, compact surface disjoint from $L$, call it $S$.  I must prove that the linking number of two such knots is $0$ where my definition of the linking number is the degree of the map
$$
T: K \times L \longrightarrow S^2
$$
$$
T(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{||x-y||}.
$$
My thought is that $K \times L$ is the boundary of $S \times L$.  If I can show that $T$ extends to $S \times L$, I'll be done.  But, I am uncertain why that should be.

Comment: Why can't you extend $T$ by the exact same formula?

Comment: @PseudoNeo Of course.  Brain isn't doing it this morning.  If you add it as an answer, I can give you your due credit.

Comment: I have done so. What is interesting is that in general you can compute the linking number of $K$ and $L$ as the (signed) intersection number of $S$ and $L$ (because of the interpretation of the degree as the signed number of elements in a level set, à la Milnor). The result you mentioned is a particular case of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition was good. Because $S$ is disjoint from $L$, you can simply extend $T$ by the same formula:
$$\begin{array}{cccc} \widehat T :& S \times L & \to & S^2 \\ & (x,y) & \mapsto & \dfrac{x-y}{\|x-y\|},\end{array}$$
and your proof works!